# How do you make geojson data for a custom google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, geojson

I think the question says it all, I have a custom google map and want to put some geojason shapes on it.
In an ideal world scan them from a sheet of paper perhaps using a pre existant image.

Just looking and gimp might be a way forward.
Still though I'll leave this question open as might be useful for others.
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ripped some code out from here.
http://blog.sallarp.com/geojson-google-maps-editor.html
Applied to my own map and got the coordinates that I needed and then had to play around with the json job done.

Feel that there should have been a program that made this all easier but can't have it all!
Richard

Comment: ust started doing this and it works, just would be nice to use some graphical package that would mean I can copy and paste get nice smooth lines etc

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the Data layer [Look at the example in google maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-simple).

Basically, you use the loadGeoJson method and pass it a valid geojson file's url

```
map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json');
```

This means that, whatever shapes you have already drawn in another source will have to be converted to geoJson format.

There are a lot of converters that can translate from-to KML, SHP, WKT, GPX and geoJson, but you still need to get from plain images to one of those formats.

Comment: Yeah, but I guess the question remains, how do I make my geoJason data from an image. So lets say I have a custom image that I want to use as my map. In my example it's a human. Then I want to add various areas to the human map - lets say parts of the body to keep it simple. How would you do that?

Comment: What would I do? Import the image as a raster layer in a desktop application like QGis, and draw over it to try and separate it into different polygons. The more complex the image, the more work it is. But I guess someone already did that for most cartographic info we use today :)

Comment: I'll give it a whirl!

Comment: Right well, getting there - installed the project got my image imported - entered an area did an export of json trouble is the coordinates don't match. How in QGis do I set the coordinates of my world.